# change visibility of textView in android

Tags: android

I m using a list view with 2 textViews. Visibility of 1 textView is set as GONE in XML. When a list item is clicked ,i want its textview to be VISIBLE. When it is clicked again,i want it to be GONE. Furter when any other item is clicked in the listView, only it's textView should be visible. I m trying it with the below code but the Textview is not becoming GONE when the same listitem is selected again.

```
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
//to change the visibility of Prevoiusly selected textview to GONE
            if (pwdView != null)
                pwdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            pwdView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.saved_pwd);
            if (pwdView.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
                pwdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            else
                pwdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Adapter code:

```
public class PwdCursorAdaptor extends CursorAdapter {
public PwdCursorAdaptor(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c, 0);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_items, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView saved_id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.saved_id);
    TextView saved_password_data=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.saved_pwd);
    int pass_index=cursor.getColumnIndex(PwdContract.PasswordEntry.COL_PASSSWORD);
    int id_index = cursor.getColumnIndex(PwdContract.PasswordEntry.COL_LOGIN_ID);
    saved_id.setText(cursor.getString(id_index));
    saved_password_data.setText(cursor.getString(pass_index));
}
```

}

Comment: You can also use invisible with this as per functionality you want it again to be visible

Comment: you have to set your textView VISIBILITY.GONE  in your .XML file.and Remove  this line in your Code
pwdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: and let me know what happenes.

Comment: @SagarAghara I want the previously visible textView to be GONE when any other list item is clicked. I have already set its visibility as GONE in XML.

Comment: show us your adapter code

Comment: @JohnJoe Adapter code added

Answer (score 0):

This is because the click listener is asynchrounus call. So you have to notify adapter that is a change is occured in data item.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (pwdView != null)
            pwdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        pwdView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.saved_pwd);
        if (pwdView.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
            pwdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        else
            pwdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


         yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});`
```

Comment: Its simply call by `yourAdapterObject.notifyDatasetChanged();` Its a override method of adapter

Comment: that is because you dit update the view in onBindview(). Add the login on OnBindView ()

Answer (score 0):

```
   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
   {
       TextView  pwdView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.saved_pwd);
        if (pwdView !=null)
       {
            pwdView.setVisibility(pwdView.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        }
         notifyDatasetChanged();
    }
   });`
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like in you adapter class

```
@Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView saved_id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.saved_id);
        final TextView saved_password_data=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.saved_pwd);
        int pass_index=cursor.getColumnIndex(PwdContract.PasswordEntry.COL_PASSSWORD);
        int id_index = cursor.getColumnIndex(PwdContract.PasswordEntry.COL_LOGIN_ID);
        saved_id.setText(cursor.getString(id_index));
        saved_password_data.setText(cursor.getString(pass_index));

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (saved_password_data.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE) {
                    saved_password_data.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else {
                    saved_password_data.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                notifyDatasetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
```

if you want saved_password_data first time should visible or gone than put visibility in     XML file as per need

Answer (score 0):

add this in onItemClick, here lBooking.size() is a list size.

```
 @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            for(int j=0;j<lBooking.size();j++){
                if(i == j){
                    view.findViewById(R.id.saved_pwd).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else {
                    lv.getChildAt(j).findViewById(R.id.saved_pwd).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }
```